# Swift generic type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a structure name **Feature**, i hope it can be generic.

```
struct Feature<T> {}
```

I have another two type: **Person**, **Dog**.

```
struct Person {}

struct Dog {}
```

What i want to ask is:
Can i call different functions or different property in **Feature** according to differrent **T**

```
//for Person type
let feature = Feature<Person>()
feature.hair// i want this visible for Person
feature.fur// i want this invisible for Person

//for Dog type
let feature = Feature<Dog>()
feature.hair// i want this invisible for Dog
feature.fur// i want this visible for Dog
```

Comment: This is "possible", but then there's nothing really generic about `Feature`. This question is basically unanswerable (in a way that would be useful to you) unless you give us some more context into the problem you're actually trying to solve

Comment: But to answer the question at face value, you could make conditional extensions like `extension Feature where T == Dog { ... }`, but I don't see what use that could offer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the full scope of your situation so I am only answering your question. See below:

```
protocol GenericFeatureProtocol {
    var eyeColor : String? { get set }
    //other shared properties & functions
}
struct Person : GenericFeatureProtocol {
    var eyeColor: String?
    var hair: String?
}
struct Dog : GenericFeatureProtocol {
    var eyeColor: String?
    var fur: String?
}
```

As you can see, the GenericFeatureProtocol defines the shared properties and functions that are to be implemented by those comforting to it. The properties respective to `Person` stay on Person, and those respective to `Dog` stay on Dog.